# StompJS: Random reconnection-loop after a while

Tags: node.js, websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket, stompjs

### Context

- 12 (testing) React Native devices are connected to our server through WebSockets.
- Randomly some devices stop receiving any server activity anymore during the day.
- These devices will be stuck in a reconnection-loop.

  - The following actions will get the devices out of the loop:

    - Restarting the client application on the devices.
    - Calling `stompSocket.deactivate()` followed by `stompSocket.activate()`.
- While looping, our server registers every time a client tries to connect to the server.

  - After diving into our server logs, we can conclude the following:

    - The client's `CONNECT` message is received by the server.
    - The server indicates that the client is `CONNECTED`.
    - After around 35 seconds the server indicates that the client is `DISCONNECTED`
- Heartbeats on the server, as well on the client are set at `10000, 10000`
- Client uses `@stomp/stompjs@6.1.2`
- In this issue I'll be zooming into the logs of one of the devices. The logs of the issue are similar across all of the devices.

### Attachments

Table of contents

1. StompJS Client configuration
2. Client-side logs of the reconnection-loop
3. Client-side logs of a successful reconnection after we restarted our server-application

---

**1. StompJS Client configuration**

```
const stompSocket: Client = new Client({
    brokerURL: WS_URL,
    appendMissingNULLonIncoming: true,
    forceBinaryWSFrames: true,
    reconnectDelay: 5000,
    connectionTimeout: 10000,
});

stompSocket.onConnect = async (): Promise<void> => {
    stompSocket.subscribe(`/topic/${topic}/messages`, async (message: IMessage): Promise<void> => {
        // Handle messages
        ...
    }
}

stompSocket.onChangeState = async (state) => {
    logDebug(`onChangeState ${JSON.stringify(state)}`, 'WS');
};

stompSocket.onWebSocketError = async (error: any) => {
    logError(`onWebSocketError ${JSON.stringify(error)}`, 'WS');
};

stompSocket.onStompError = async (error: any) => {
    logError(`onStompError ${JSON.stringify(error)}`, 'WS');
};

stompSocket.onWebSocketClose = async (evt: any) => {
    logWarn(`onWebSocketClose(): ${JSON.stringify(evt)}`, 'WS');
};

stompSocket.onDisconnect = async (receipt: any) => {
    logWarn(`onDisconnect ${JSON.stringify(receipt)}`, 'WS');
};
```

---

**2. Logs of the reconnecting loop (client-side)**

- One of the client stops receiving activity from the server, even though the server receives all the `CONNECT` messages from the client.
- I can't figure out why the `CONNECT` message is send **after** the 10000ms timeout is triggered and the connection is trying to close.

```
// No previous logs in the past couple hours.
09:14:33 STOMP did not receive server activity for the last 26911ms
09:14:33 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:14:43 STOMP did not receive server activity for the last 36919ms
09:14:43 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:14:53 STOMP did not receive server activity for the last 46919ms
09:14:53 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:15:03 STOMP did not receive server activity for the last 56923ms
09:15:03 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:15:13 STOMP did not receive server activity for the last 66927ms
09:15:13 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:15:23 STOMP did not receive server activity for the last 76931ms
09:15:23 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:15:33 STOMP did not receive server activity for the last 86934ms
09:15:33 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:15:33 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Socket closed"}
09:15:33 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
09:15:33 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Socket closed"}
09:15:33 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
09:15:38 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
09:15:48 STOMP Connection not established in 10000ms, closing socket
09:15:48 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:15:49 STOMP Web Socket Opened...
09:15:49 STOMP
    >>> CONNECT
    accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
    heart-beat:10000,10000

09:16:26 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
09:16:26 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"code":1002,"reason":""}
09:16:26 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
09:16:31 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
09:16:41 STOMP Connection not established in 10000ms, closing socket
09:16:41 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:16:41 STOMP Web Socket Opened...
09:16:41 STOMP
    >>> CONNECT
    accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
    heart-beat:10000,10000

09:17:16 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
09:17:16 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"code":1002,"reason":""}
09:17:16 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
09:17:21 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
09:17:31 STOMP Connection not established in 10000ms, closing socket
09:17:31 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:17:31 STOMP Web Socket Opened...
09:17:31 STOMP
    >>> CONNECT
    accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
    heart-beat:10000,10000

09:18:06 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
09:18:06 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"code":1002,"reason":""}
09:18:06 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
09:18:11 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
09:18:21 STOMP Connection not established in 10000ms, closing socket
09:18:21 STOMP Issuing close on the websocket
09:18:21 STOMP Web Socket Opened...
09:18:21 STOMP
    >>> CONNECT
    accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
    heart-beat:10000,10000
// This keeps going for ever, until manual intervention.
```

---

**3. Client-side logs of a successful reconnection after we restarted our server-application**

- These logs show what we should expect when the client tries to reconnect when the server is down.
- The server application was restarting between `07:04:11` and `07:05:15`.
- It is expected that our apache server returns `503` while restarting.
- When the server application was back, the client tried to reconnect at `07:05:20`. In the same second the connection was established and the server returned a `CONNECTED` back.

```
// No previous logs in the past couple hours.
07:04:11 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:11 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"code":1001,"reason":""}
07:04:11 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:16 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:16 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:17 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:17 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:17 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:22 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:22 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:22 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:22 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:22 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:27 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:27 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:27 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:27 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:27 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:32 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:32 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:32 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:32 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:32 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:37 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:38 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:38 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:38 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:38 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:43 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:43 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:43 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:43 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:43 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:48 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:48 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:48 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:48 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:48 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:53 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:54 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:54 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:54 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:54 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:04:59 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:04:59 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:59 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:04:59 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:04:59 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:05:04 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:05:04 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:05:04 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:05:04 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:05:04 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:05:09 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:05:09 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:05:09 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:05:09 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:05:09 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:05:14 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:05:15 WS onWebSocketError {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:05:15 STOMP Connection closed to wss://example.com/websocket
07:05:15 WS onWebSocketClose {"isTrusted":false,"message":"Expected HTTP 101 response but was '503 Service Unavailable'"}
07:05:15 STOMP STOMP: scheduling reconnection in 5000ms
07:05:20 STOMP Opening Web Socket...
07:05:20 STOMP Web Socket Opened...
07:05:20 STOMP
    >>> CONNECT
    accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
    heart-beat:10000,10000

07:05:20 STOMP
    <<< CONNECTED
    heart-beat:10000,10000
    version:1.2
    content-length:0

07:05:20 STOMP connected to server undefined 
07:05:20 TRACE ws.service.ts: stompSocket.onConnect() was called
// ...
```

Comment: The client receives a 1002 WS error when it tries to connect again. What did de server send back as a response on the CONNECT? Any chance that the response is causing a protocol violation?

Comment: Please see attachment 3 at `07:05:20` for the response on the `CONNECT`. (:

Comment: Yes, but that one is after a restart, right? There your logs show that the server response with a `CONNECTED` message, in the failing reconnect it does not